# Athena Query: Convert Server Timing JSON to Date-wise Aggregated Columns

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have data in below mentioned format

| Date | serverTiming |
| --- | --- |
| 29-12-2023 | [{"name":"react","dur":450},{"name":"agg","dur":380}] |
| 30-11-2023 | [{"name":"agg","dur":460},{"name":"react","dur":520}] |

and want to convert this to below format using Athena query

| Date | Agg | React |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29-12-2023 | 380 | 450 |
| 30-11-2023 | 460 | 520 |

I have tried a few approaches but unable to get the required result.
could you please suggest some way.

This is what I have tried

```html
with base as (
select
datepart
,cast(json_extract(attribution, '$.navigationEntry.serverTiming') as array<map<varchar,varchar>>)  as serverTiming
from frontend.ui_stats_new
where datepart > to_iso8601(current_date - interval '4' day) 
AND metricname ='TTFB' 
AND page in ('searchPage') 
and attribution is not null
limit 10
)
 
select datepart,serverTiming_obj['name'],serverTiming_obj['duration']
from base 
cross join unnest(serverTiming) as t(serverTiming_obj)
```

but is giving result by splitting single row into multiple rows

this is the result i am getting
[image]

Comment: what code have you tried and what results is it giving you?

Comment: Updated my approach and what i tried in the question @TimMylott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest option (if AWS Athena supports it) is to use Trino's [`json-query`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-query) which has much better JSON Path support:

```
-- sample data
with dataset (Date, serverTiming) as (
    values ('29-12-2023', '[{"name":"react","dur":450},{"name":"agg","dur":380}]'),
        ('30-11-2023', '[{"name":"agg","dur":460},{"name":"react","dur":520}]')
)

-- query
select Date,
    json_query(serverTiming, 'lax $[*]?(@.name == "agg").dur' WITHOUT ARRAY WRAPPER) Agg,
    json_query(serverTiming, 'lax $[*]?(@.name == "react").dur' WITHOUT ARRAY WRAPPER) React
from dataset;
```

Output:

| Date | Agg | React |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29-12-2023 | 380 | 450 |
| 30-11-2023 | 460 | 520 |

Otherwise you can use combination of [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) instead of unnesting (bunch of `filter` + `element_at`'s) or pivot by applying group by and use aggregation functions like `arbitrary` (I will dive deeper if the first option will not work, but it should since Athena Engine v.3).